# Can we join two collections from different database in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, document, mongodb-compass

I want to join two different collection from diffrent database so please let me know is it possible we can join two collection of diffrent database?

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of joins in MongoDB, instead, there is a concept of [aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), but this is applicable only in the same DB. for different Database you should consider doing it manually on the **service layer** of your app